# XmlSerializer attribute System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute is not valid in

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, axis2c

I am getting the following error in a .Net 4.6.2 client app:

> Unable to save the event: XmlSerializer attribute
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute is not valid in
>   parentOid. Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute
>   and XmlAnyElement attributes are supported when IsWrapped is true.

This is an application that has been around for a long time, and the Axis2/C WebService method has not changed in a very long time.  What has changed is a new method was added to the web service recently and earlier this year the application up was upgraded from .Net 3.5 to 4.6.2 and moved from VS2010 to VS2015.

The .Net Client app has always consumed the WebService by "Add Service Reference" and it has never had problems before.  Has something changed between .Net 3.5 & 4.6.2 or between VS2010 and VS2015?

### For what it is worth, the WebService itself is implmented in a old, dead framework of Axis2/C and runs under an Apache Web Server that is all developed in VS2008.

here is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr" name="CatalogMgr">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr">

            <xsd:element name="updateEventData">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="eventData" type="tns:EventDataRowUpdate"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="updateEventDataResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="updateCategory">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="category" type="tns:CategoryRowUpdate"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="updateCategoryResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="appendImageGallery">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="imageGalleries" type="tns:ImageGallerySet"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="appendImageGalleryResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getImages">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="galleryId" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="startImage" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                        <xsd:element name="pageSize" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getImagesResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="imageGallery" type="tns:ImageGallery" nillable="true"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>      

            <xsd:element name="getNode">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="nodeId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                        <xsd:element name="ignoreActiveFlag" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getNodeResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="currentNode" type="tns:Node"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getParentNode">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="nodeId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getParentNodeResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="parentNode" type="tns:ParentNode" nillable="true"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getImagePage">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="galleryId" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="startImage" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="pageIndex" type="xsd:int"/>
                        <xsd:element name="pageSize" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getImagePageResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="imageGallery" type="tns:ImageGallery" nillable="true"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="appendCategory">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="categories" type="tns:CategorySet"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="appendCategoryResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="updateImageGallery">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="imageGallery" type="tns:ImageGalleryRowUpdate"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="updateImageGalleryResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="setActiveFlag">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="isActive" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="setActiveFlagResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="deleteEventNode">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="deleteFavorites" type="xsd:boolean" default="false"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="deleteEventNodeResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="moveEventNode">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="parentOid" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="afterSiblingOid" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="moveEventNodeResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="sortCatgory">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="parentOid" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="sortDirection" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="sortCatgoryResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="currentNode" type="tns:Node"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="reorderCatgory">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="childrenOid" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="parentOid" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="reorderCatgoryResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="currentNode" type="tns:Node"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getAllImgGalleryDescendants">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="parentOid" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="getAllImgGalleryDescendantsResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="imageGallery" type="tns:ImageGalleryRow" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>      

            <!-- ************************************************ -->
            <xsd:complexType name="ParentNode">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="Node">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="children" type="tns:Child" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="Child">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="active" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="isGallery" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="Category">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="deleted" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="expanded" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="errStr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="CategorySet">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="category" type="tns:Category" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="parentOID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="ImageGallery">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="displayStartTrim" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="displayEndTrim" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="active" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="startIndex" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="totalCount" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="images" type="tns:Image" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="errStr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="ImageGalleryRow">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="objectId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="relativePath" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="relativeTNPath" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="filenamePattern" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="useOriginalFilenames" type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element name="digits" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="seq" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="seqPlacement" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="displayStartTrim" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="displayEndTrim" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="isActive" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="deleted" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="errStr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="ImageGallerySet">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="imageGallery" type="tns:ImageGalleryRow" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="parentOID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="EventDataRowUpdate">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="activeRootOid" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="seq" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="CategoryRowUpdate">
                <xsd:sequence>          
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="expanded" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="ImageGalleryRowUpdate">
                <xsd:sequence>          
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="relativePath" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="filenamePattern" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="useOriginalFilenames" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="digits" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="seq" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="seqPlacement" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="displayStartTrim" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="displayEndTrim" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="deleted" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="Image">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="tag" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="pliCnt" type="tns:PriceListItemCount" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="PriceListItemCount">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="qty" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="updateCategoryRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:updateCategory"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateCategoryResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:updateCategoryResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="appendImageGalleryRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:appendImageGallery"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="appendImageGalleryResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:appendImageGalleryResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getImagesRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getImages"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getImagesResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getImagesResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getNodeRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getNode"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getNodeResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getNodeResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getParentNodeRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getParentNode"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getParentNodeResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getParentNodeResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getImagePageRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getImagePage"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getImagePageResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getImagePageResponse"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="appendCategoryRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:appendCategory"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="appendCategoryResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:appendCategoryResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateImageGalleryRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:updateImageGallery"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateImageGalleryResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:updateImageGalleryResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateEventDataRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:updateEventData"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateEventDataResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:updateEventDataResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="setActiveFlagRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:setActiveFlag"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="setActiveFlagResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:setActiveFlagResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="deleteEventNodeRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteEventNode"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="deleteEventNodeResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteEventNodeResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="moveEventNodeRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:moveEventNode"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="moveEventNodeResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:moveEventNodeResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="sortCatgoryRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:sortCatgory"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sortCatgoryResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:sortCatgoryResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="reorderCatgoryRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:reorderCatgory"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="reorderCatgoryResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:reorderCatgoryResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="getAllImgGalleryDescendantsRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllImgGalleryDescendants"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getAllImgGalleryDescendantsResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllImgGalleryDescendantsResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="CatalogMgr">
        <wsdl:operation name="updateCategory">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:updateCategoryRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:updateCategoryResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="appendImageGallery">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:appendImageGalleryRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:appendImageGalleryResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getImages">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getImagesRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getImagesResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getNode">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getNodeRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getNodeResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getParentNode">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getParentNodeRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getParentNodeResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getImagePage">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getImagePageRequest"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getImagePageResponse"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="appendCategory">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:appendCategoryRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:appendCategoryResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="updateImageGallery">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:updateImageGalleryRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:updateImageGalleryResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>    
        <wsdl:operation name="updateEventData">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:updateEventDataRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:updateEventDataResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>    
        <wsdl:operation name="setActiveFlag">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:setActiveFlagRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:setActiveFlagResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="deleteEventNode">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:deleteEventNodeRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:deleteEventNodeResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="moveEventNode">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:moveEventNodeRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:moveEventNodeResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="reorderCatgory">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:reorderCatgoryRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:reorderCatgoryResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="sortCatgory">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:sortCatgoryRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sortCatgoryResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getAllImgGalleryDescendants">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getAllImgGalleryDescendantsRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getAllImgGalleryDescendantsResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="CatalogMgrSOAP" type="tns:CatalogMgr">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="updateCategory">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/updateCategory"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="appendImageGallery">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/appendImageGallery"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="getImages">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/getImages"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="getNode">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/getNode"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="getParentNode">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/getParentNode"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="getImagePage">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/getImagePage"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="appendCategory">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/appendCategory"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="updateImageGallery">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/updateImageGallery"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="updateEventData">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/updateEventData"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="setActiveFlag">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/setActiveFlag"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="deleteEventNode">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/deleteEventNode"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="moveEventNode">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/moveEventNode"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="reorderCatgory">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/reorderCatgory"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="sortCatgory">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/sortCatgory"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="getAllImgGalleryDescendants">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmpp:catalogmgr/getAllImgGalleryDescendants"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="CatalogMgr">
        <wsdl:port name="CatalogMgrSOAP" binding="tns:CatalogMgrSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/axis2/services/CatalogMgr"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840901/wcf-serialization-problems-with-wsdl-file-created-by-java-tools).

Comment: Scott, so my understanding is that I need to add [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)] to the request objects in the Reference.cs files, is that correct?  Why was this working for me in the past and isn't now?  Is it a .Net 4.6.2 thing or a VS2015 issue?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not actually familiar with it. I just googled the second part of the error messsge and saw the other answer. In both cases the problem occurred when regenersting a service reference. Something in the wsdl changed that caused the error. The other answer was specific about the details so it looked like a match. But I've never encountered it myself. (That's why I commented instead of answering.)

Comment: Are you able to provide us with the WSDL for the service? So we can try out generating a client ourselves? You can scrub out any URLs, replace them with example.com

Comment: gnud, it has been a busy week, I just posted the WSDL, unedited